# Communication between applications

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, com, activex

I have 3 choices to use : sockets, activeX, com , in order to communicate between applications on one computer. Which is faster ?

Comment: -1: *Which-is-faster* -type question can **always** be answered by just trying it. Apart from that, without more details on your specific problem, any answer would just be guessing.

Comment: for large amount of data, probably sockets will be faster. Why don't you test it?

Comment: Disagree with space_cowboy: a useful experiment to implement all three options for realistic data for his case would surely take 10+ hours of development time. It is appropriate to ask the community what their experience is with these methods in this case.

Comment: you have more options: pipes, windows messages (WM_COPYDATA), sync objects... is there a reason you're restricted to the ones you listed? And more importantly: what are you using it for? Obviously the different IPC methods exist for a reason, the question is never simply "is one faster than the other". Your specific context will decide. If by "communicate" you mean just trigger an event, then a windows message is probably fastest. Please clarify

Comment: I need to communicate with 3rd party product. And  they offer only the one listed. And by communicate i mean transfering data

Comment: @Zlobaton: Obviously by communicate you mean transferring data. That is not a helpful clarification. One-way? Two-way? How frequent? What kind of data? How much throughput? Asynchronous? Streaming? Does the sender expect a reply based on data?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as this runs on one machine, interprocess communication is fundamentally throttled by the bus bandwidth.  A memory-to-memory copy, whether that's done in the TCP/IP stack, the named pipe support code or shared memory.  Which makes them all equally efficient.

One detail matters though, the amount of data that's transferred and the number of software layers you travel through to get the job done.  The memory bus bandwidth only throttles when the amount of data is large.  That isn't necessarily the case for a remote procedure call protocol like COM.  Only the arguments of the function call needs to be serialized, that could be only a handful of bytes if you don't pass arrays.  Now the overhead starts to matter, there's a fair amount of it when you use a high-level protocol like COM.

The obvious disadvantage of using sockets is that you'll have to write all the de/serialization code yourself.  Nontrivial if the protocol with the component isn't simple.  Trading your working hours for convenience is the typical choice, only you can make it.

Answer (score 11):

Well, think about it - socket is the lowest level, COM is using sockets, ActiveX is using COM. So which one is faster? Of course, sockets. But that is only if you are asking about program execution speed and data transfer rates. Developing programs using sockets, however, can be much harder if you don't know what you are doing. Not to mention that you possibly can come up with some bad implementation that will be worse than COM. Also, there are not that much of reusable components you can get for sockets as you get using ActiveX, not to mention that if you want to communicate with MS Office, you will have to use COM.

Comment: Actually COM uses LRPC/LPC (not sockets) in the cross process but same machine case. LRPC/LPC is very efficient (uses shared memory).

Comment: @Steve: Sockets on the same machine are using IPC as well. Shared memory won't work over the network though (there are solutions but expensive and not very efficient and reliable).

Answer (score 3):

You don't give much detail about what you're trying to do or what considerations you need to make. For example, by "fast" do you mean high bandwidth? Low latency? Is there a possibility you might need to communicate across computers later? Etc.

That said, ActiveX is a special case of COM ([introduction to activeX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa751972.aspx)). If you're familiar with COM or ActiveX already, and depending on what exactly you're trying to do, you may be able to get away with writing relatively little code because MS dev tools can handle a lot of it for you.

If you're not familiar with it though, it's a fairly complex technology that may be tricky to wrap your head around. So if you're just trying to implement some basic inter-process communication it may be easier to go with sockets. On the other hand, that may require more low level work on your part.

Answer (score 2):

I would also delegate the IPC to a framework e.g. ACE (adaptive communication framework).
Ace's implementation for example, is stable and it's cross platform.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveX is more or less a fancy marketing name on COM (an ActiveX component / control is an object that just supports the IUnknown interface), so your choice is really down to COM vs Socket.

For cross process communication, you *can* write something faster with sockets... if you're a good socket and Windows programmer, because you will be on your own, as Sockets will basically do nothing to help you. That does not mean COM is not fast, or has bad performance, but you always theoretically can do better than an out-of-the-box system, but only if you master the whole thing.

On last thing, if you need to communicate with 3rd party products or other platforms than Windows, Sockets are more portable.

Answer (score 1):

It may not actually matter which is faster. If so then choose the method that will be the most convenient to develop and maintain. It may be possible to save your own time even if you can't save any measurable runtime.

Comment: Some of us take pride in doing the best job possible.

Comment: @Jay Choosing the most convenient and maintainable approach often allows you to do the best job possible. I presume you don't write all your programs in machine code!!

Comment: @Jay Also notice which answer has been accepted – the one which says essentially the same as mine!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say which is faster, but using COM is certainly the most flexible of the choices you listed. Unless you like grovelling through byte streams.